# SSRS error when passing parameter in url

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm very new to CRM and SSRS. I'm trying to view an SSRS report in CRM through iframe. I'm passing a parameter named CUST to the report using the url. The url is :

http://myserver.com/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?id={E2D2E6AF-DFB2-E511-A0F2-B8AC6F7E4B9E}&helpID=report_name.rdl&action=filter&rs:Command=Render&CUST=A23E3D82-4C3E-E411-9876-B8AC6F7E4B9E_98A75285-D8B3-DD11-A4F8-001E4FF54233

when I try opening the url it gives the below error :

[image]

but when I try opening the report with removing "rs:Command=Render" and "CUST" it opens fine

I'm using MSCRM 4.0 and SSRS 2008

Can any body help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. The report parameters have to be hidden and I had to edit the link to show the report from the ReportServer instead of the current one I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link, If you unable to understand then let me know.

http://msprojectnow.com/blog/sql-reporting-services-2008-r2-using-urls-to-call-reports-with-single-and-multi-value-parameters-html-and-report-viewer-applicable